# Encoding an APNs token in JSON for node-apn (parse-server)

Tags: json, apple-push-notifications, token, parse-server, node-apn

I've deployed a parse-server app in Heroku that I'd been developing locally using Docker. This app uses push notifications, and so needs access to some crypto data to play with APNs.

Locally I mounted a volume with the token key file in it. On Heroku this isn't an option, and I don't want to bundle the key in the package unencrypted. I've been trying to encode the token key in the JSON argument to the "PARSE_SERVER_PUSH" environment variable in different ways. It seems what's needed is a Buffer, but I have no idea how to represent such a thing in JSON, and I haven't found anything through some searching.

I'm currently using this at my push config:

```
{"ios": 
    {
        "token": {
        "key": {"type":"Buffer","data":[45, 45, ... 45]},
        "keyId": "MYKEYID",
        "teamId": "MYTEAMID" 
        },
        "topic": "com.myApp", 
        "production": false
    }
}
```

But the server chokes on the 'key' field:

```
2019-01-23T19:47:36.725181+00:00 app[web.1]: VError: Failed loading token key: path must be a string or Buffer
2019-01-23T19:47:36.725191+00:00 app[web.1]:     at prepareToken (/parse-server/node_modules/apn/lib/credentials/token/prepare.js:15:13)
2019-01-23T19:47:36.725193+00:00 app[web.1]:     at config (/parse-server/node_modules/apn/lib/config.js:43:31)
2019-01-23T19:47:36.725194+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new Client (/parse-server/node_modules/apn/lib/client.js:21:19)
2019-01-23T19:47:36.725195+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new Provider (/parse-server/node_modules/apn/lib/provider.js:12:19)
2019-01-23T19:47:36.725201+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._createProvider (/parse-server/node_modules/@parse/push-adapter/lib/APNS.js:251:22)
2019-01-23T19:47:36.725203+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new APNS (/parse-server/node_modules/@parse/push-adapter/lib/APNS.js:81:29)
2019-01-23T19:47:36.725204+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new ParsePushAdapter (/parse-server/node_modules/@parse/push-adapter/lib/ParsePushAdapter.js:65:40)
2019-01-23T19:47:36.725205+00:00 app[web.1]:     at loadAdapter (/parse-server/lib/Adapters/AdapterLoader.js:31:16)
2019-01-23T19:47:36.725206+00:00 app[web.1]:     at loadAdapter (/parse-server/lib/Adapters/AdapterLoader.js:24:12)
2019-01-23T19:47:36.725207+00:00 app[web.1]:     at getPushController (/parse-server/lib/Controllers/index.js:230:54)
```

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

EDIT: The documentation (https://github.com/node-apn/node-apn/blob/master/doc/provider.markdown) suggests it's possible:

> token.key {Buffer|String} The filename of the provider token key (as
>   supplied by Apple) to load from disk, **or a Buffer/String containing
>   the key data**.